# Burninate [moving]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[moving](/questions/tagged/moving) seems to have tons of completely different questions tagged with it. No tag wiki. There are so many uses of the word moving that I can't even count:

- moving a file
- moving some text
- moving in an animation
- moving the mouse
- moving a window around
- moving certain blocks of code
- moving a scroll bar
- etc.

**Way** too general, vague, and all that burninate-y stuff.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV2vm.png]

Edit:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm85C.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, for many of those questions the poster just didn't understand how the tag system works.  On one question I removed four tags:  [lag](/questions/tagged/lag) [smooth](/questions/tagged/smooth) [moving](/questions/tagged/moving) and  [ball](/questions/tagged/ball).

Awk... 21 questions tagged [ball](/questions/tagged/ball).  86 questions tagged [smooth](/questions/tagged/smooth)... **>_<**

Comment: Should ball and smooth be burninated?